# Rendering differences with character vectors in Rmarkdown notebooks between RStudio and rmarkdown::render()

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

I have run into something that is baffling me, and I feel like I must be missing something obvious.

When I print a character vector in an Rmarkdown notebook by simply putting the name of the vector (`abc`, say) in a block, this renders as expected in RStudio. But when I render the notebook with `rmarkdown::render()` it prints twice. Once as expected:

```
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

and once with lots of extra space:

```
a
    
b
    
c
```

Using `print(abc)` solves the trouble and prints the same either way, but I would rather not have to do that...

Also, rendering with `output_format = "html_document"` renders as expected. It is only with the `html_notebook` output that I see this.

This does not affect numeric vectors or factors, only character vectors, it seems.

A gist with a test notebook is here: https://gist.github.com/jashapiro/20ad401c9834638e4dee699e44ab7167

Is there an argument I should be adding to `rmarkdown::render()` to make it behave as RStudio does?

I have tried `--vanilla` and `xfun::Rscript_call()`, but get the same results.

I have tested this with rmarkdown 2.6 & 2.7 R 4.03 & 4.04. I feel like perhaps I didn't have this problem with earlier versions, but I can't say for certain.

Answer (score 0):

I have apparently encountered a known bug; one that has been around for a long while: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1568